Why are there so many ninjas if exams are only held once a year and only a few (or even none) pass?
In the (only yearly held!) genin and chunin exams only very few (if at all) ninjas pass. And the ones that do not pass maybe even die in the exams.
Yet, there seem to be endless chunin and jonin in the course of the story. Just take the regular jonin, the anbu, the teachers, the count- and name-less one-shot-dead chunin.
Just take the attack on the hidden leaf village when Naruto's first chunin exam was held. So many ninjas. Where did they came from with so few and hard exams?
How is this explained?

https://www.reddit.com/r/Naruto/comments/2iu9c7/the_amount_of_chunin_during_the_4th_war/

This question might be related If there are thousands of ninjas in Konoha, why was Tsunade always short of ninjas for the missions in the anime?

Also: How were there 80,000 ninjas in the Shinobi World War in Naruto?

They've been doing the exams for years. Im sure that plenty would have arisen over a long amount of time

I think it's plausible. Take Hyuga Neji for example: After getting destroyed by Naruto in the Chunin Exams (correct me if I'm wrong), he becomes a Jonin after 3 years. Then there's Gaara, who...doesn't pass, and anyway almost gets beaten by Lee and is in an epic fight with Sasuke when the attack occurs. After the time skip, he becomes the Kazekage.
Yes, that may be partly a storyline thing that the authors do without explanation, but then you see Naruto's training, and obviously, he can be Jonin level already. Even Sakura is now strong enough to destroy the arena, let alone become a chunin. Temari is played by Shikamaru, then becomes a jonin after the time skip.
Many ninjas fail and fail and fail, but the ones you see are those who were able to get through eventually. Some of them may have had to retake a few times. So the tons of Jonin and even one shot kill Chunin are all very skilled ninjas; it's just that the villains in the story do a very good job of wiping them out (they are god-level after all, e.g., Pain and Madara). I hope the logic makes sense.

It likely isn't explained and is an extremely common practice in fiction. Filler characters are written as needed all the time.
If it helps your imagination, then just imagine that in some years there are large batches that pass the exams and in other years, small batches. You've only witnessed a year with the small batches that pass the exams.
Not every detail needs a fleshed-out logical explanation in fiction, some can be left to the consumers to imagine for themselves.
Cheers.
